# C++ API in Python - SWIG, Redesign, or Message Passing

Tags: c++, python, api, swig

Ok, quick, and hopefully easy question here...

I have a large C++ API that is basically a sockets API with a top level XML type protocol.  This is a distributed source package from a company.  All of the source code is written into header files (including function implementations) for some odd reason (I guess they figure it is easier for developers to import an H file and not have to worry about compiling multiple cpp files??).  The source is also available in C, Java, and .NET.

The application that I am writing is in Python, on Linux, and needs to use this API through Python.  My three options seem to be either running the applications separately with a message passing protocol between them, running SWIG (or similar) to generate a Python hook-in, or to reimplement all the source code into Python.  Ultimately, I'd like to make it as asynchronous as possible (already using Twisted in other parts of the application).

Using SWIG seems to be the quickest, but there are many custom typed structures that are used in passing in and out of functions, as well as returns from functions, which I have heard can be a bit of an issue with SWIG.

I'd rather not have to write a message protocol as that creates another point of failure and two different source codes, in two different languages, that I have to manage.  Reimplementing the C++ code in Python may ultimately be a good solution, but that is going to require a large amount of effort and time.

My question is, does SWIG seem like a good idea, and if so, will I need to write C++ files to compile that wrap the headers, or should I just forget SWIG and look into something else?

I appreciate any help or thoughts.  Thanks.

**EDIT**: Turns out I misspoke earlier...there is a lot of the source code in header files, but I found a bunch of `.lib` and `.a` files as well.  Is it possible to use SWIG, Boost, or similar on these types of files included?  Or do I need to write a top level API over those and try that way? So far my attempts have failed miserably.

**SOLUTION**:  I ended up just implementing my own API straight from Python.  Turns out that the protocol spec was not that complex and the C++ libraries actually made it more difficult than it needed to be.  I also have the added bonus of building the lib inside an asynchronous framework, instead of having to do threading with the synchronous calls.

Comment: Implementation of templates functions often have to be included in .h files.  That may be why so much is in header files.

Comment: Haven't seen any templates yet...just plane classes and functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SWIG would usually be my preferred solution for problems like this. "Custom typed" structures can be wrapped perfectly sensibly. The thing you will need to watch out for though is the [limitations of the SWIG parser](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn8) if you've got *everything* in the header files.

Comment: Thanks for the response...That is what I was thinking as well...I don't think any of the parser limitations would apply, fortunately.  There are several source files, so I will need to figure out how to SWIG them all and not get parser/compiler errors.

Comment: Another benefit of using SWIG is that you have the option to wrap those API calls with your own low-level instrumentation logic. And since you're only maintaining the "glue code" you can seamlessly take advantage of any upgrades to the "back end" that don't change the interface.

Comment: @awoodland, Thank you for your reply earlier, but I misspoke when I wrote the question...please refer to the edit in my post

Answer (score 3):

You should consider [boost_python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/python/doc/index.html).  It gives you a lot of control over the python/c++ interface and it is actually easy to use.  There are some simple [tutorials](http://www.boostpro.com/writing/bpl.html) about using boost_python.  Since boost_python is c++ itself, you avoid adding a third technology (swig) into your project.

Comment: With boost, won't I need to edit all of the source files to wrap the some 100+ classes with the class wrappers?

Comment: You don't need to edit the source files at all.  In fact, you should reject any solution that requires you do that.  You #include the header files of the code you are trying to wrap.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.  I'll check it out in addition to SWIG and see which works out better.

Comment: Thank you for your reply earlier, but I misspoke when I wrote the question...please refer to the edit in my post

Comment: The fact that there are .lib files probably means that you don't have all the source code.  You can still use boost_python to make the code visible from python.